# jquery code in drupal 7 module

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

How to dispaly the following code in drupal 7 module

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dubturbo1.counselstime.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script>jwplayer.key="76oyax0SAVqgDM580AJ3+K23kIuN8HFkgahYRQ=="</script>
    <div id="my-video"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('my-video').setup({
            file: 'http://192.168.1.150/sathya/video_test_512kb.mp4',
            width: '500',
            height: '300',
    controls: 'false',
    autostart: 'true',
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add it to a JS file, either within your module (if necessary) or otherwise just put it within your themes JS file if you don't need a module for what you are doing.

Wrap it in a Drupal behaviours wrapper:

```
(function($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.setupVideo = {
        attach: function (context) {

          wplayer('my-video').setup({
            file: 'http://192.168.1.150/sathya/video_test_512kb.mp4',
            width: '500',
            height: '300',
            controls: 'false',
            autostart: 'true'
          });

        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

You will also need to add the first JS file (the jwplayer stuff) in there too. Add it as a line in your theme or add it to your module:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/js/jwplayer.js', 'file');
```

Comment: No problem! I +1'd you so you should now have enough rep to upvote and accept the answer :D